# If mysql results = 1 then . Is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello I wanna check to see if there is all ready a user in the db with the same username before adding it to the db ... but I'm getting a white page.

```
$sql2="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' ";
$result2=msyql_query($sql2,);
if (mysql_num_rows($result2)==0) { 
echo "A account is all ready here" ;

 }
else{
```

That's the main bit were it checks.

Here is my full code:

```
include('config.php');

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);


print_r ($_SESSION) ;

if ($_SESSION['number_three'] == 3 ) {

  $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$avatar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['avatar']);
$starter = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['starter']);
$gender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);

$_SESSION['start'] = $starter;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE pic='$_SESSION[start]'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$values = mysql_fetch_array($result);


$sql2="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' ";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2,);
if (mysql_num_rows($result2)==0) { 
echo "A account is all ready here" ;

 }
else{


$_SESSION['test'] = $values['name'];


mysql_query("INSERT INTO users 
(username, password, email, avatar, gender) VALUES
('$user','$pass','$email','$avatar','$gender'  )
 ") or die(mysql_error());  



 mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_pokemon 
(pokemon, belongsto, slot) VALUES
('".$_SESSION['test']."','$user','1'  )
 ") or die(mysql_error());  


  unset($_SESSION['number_three']); 


} else {

echo " You do not ment to be here ! Go Away !";


}
}
```

If I take the top part of the code out in the first bit script works but does not check if user is already in the db.....  with the script has it is now I'm getting white page with the top bit of code in first post code bit also I am not getting any errors....

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors in the code. Enable error messaging or take a look at the PHP error logs.

Comment: Don't you want to check if `mysql_num_rows($result2)==1`, not if `mysql_num_rows($result2)==0`?

Comment: No i wanna check if the user has a account not if the user has not got a account

Comment: This forum is for helping with coding . For ppl who can't see the errors or ent has good has other coders it ent there fault ! so grow up !

Comment: try adding E_STRICT too, if youre < PHP 5.4.0

Comment: where is your `session_start()`

Answer (score 2):

```
$result2=mssql_query($sql2,);
```

You're calling [`mssql_query`](http://php.net/mssql_query), not [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query).

Answer (score 1):

`mssql_query`? Try `mysql_query` instead.

Comment: still getting white page after changing it

Comment: Check your php error log. (or add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before your code).

Comment: i have has you can see by my code and not getting any ... only a white page

Comment: You haven't enabled error reporting at the beginning of your code, you have added it after including another file.

Comment: I have put it after the include ..... and still shows no errors think i mite be missing a { or a } some were

Comment: That's one of the many syntax errors. Show your whole code, **or** (I recommend this option) try debugging yourself. It's very educative, and useful for future software development.

Answer (score 1):

**Use PDO with exception throwing:**

```
try {
    $PDO = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

    //use $PDO->query(); Errors will be thrown and you'll be able to see them.  This way you don't have to check the boolean return values on queries.

} catch(PDOException $error) {
    echo $error->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: +1 - in 2012 (nearly 2013) there really is no excuse for using ```mysql_*``` functions anymore; **they're deprecated for a reason**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the only problem, but first off, on the line where you make that second query, you're calling `mssql_query` rather than `mysql_query`, which is the query function for Microsoft SQL Server databases, and wouldn't know how to get results back from MySQL.

Comment: I have changed that but still getting a white page

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding E_STRICT if you have older PHP than 5.4.0.
2. Add `or die (mysql_error());` to know if there's an error in the query.
3. Try using `if (!mysql_num_rows($result2))` or `if (mysql_num_rows($result2) < 1)`